# Possible to have separate shortcuts for different text-to-speech voices?

Tags: language, accessibility, text-to-speech, voiceover

I know that it is possible to make Mac OS X to read the text with a keyboard shortcut.

System preferences ***Dictation & Speech->Text to Speech*** tab
[image]

But suppose I'm multilingual. Is it possible to have different shortcuts for different languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I couldn't find a way to assign keyboard shortcut directly, an acceptable solution turned out to be much simpler than one might think.

Create a new Service in Automator. By default it takes selected text in any Application and lets you to do something to it. Choose *Speak Text* from the *Text* category and select any active voice from the drop-down. Now save the new Service under some descriptive name and you will be able to assign a desired keyboard shortcut to it from: *Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Text > "Name of the Service"*.

Done.